# Multicolumn issue with first item

Tags: css, multiple-columns

What am I seeing here? I do not mind the rest of the paragraphs do not line up, but the top ones must. What am I missing?

Browsers Fx 19 and Chrome 24 full screen on OSX Mountain Lion

**NOTE:** it goes away in a jsfiddle due to the normalised css that is inserted automatically

[JSFIDDLE without normalised CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/AsMH9/show/)
[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#multicolumn { 
-moz-column-count:3; /* Firefox */
-webkit-column-count:3; /* Safari and Chrome */
 column-count:3; 
-moz-column-gap: 10px;
-webkit-column-gap: 10px;
column-gap: 10px;
-moz-column-rule: 1px solid #000;
-webkit-column-rule: 1px solid #000;
column-rule:1px solid #000;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="multicolumn"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec nulla lorem, tincidunt in pulvinar non</p>
<p>Suspendisse est odio, porttitor non semper porttitor, sagittis in enim. Aenean mollis elit dapibus</p>
<p>Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; </p>
<p>Etiam imperdiet suscipit odio, posuere ultrices diam porttitor nec. In tincidunt iaculis neque</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum porta consectetur sapien, </p>
<p>Donec tortor mauris, congue sit amet imperdiet sed, vehicula vel eros.</p>
<p>Curabitur porttitor mattis felis et placerat. Nulla facilisi. Curabitur varius imperdiet sapien,</p>
<p>in vulputate quam auctor id. In quis eros eget sapien dignissim porttitor.</p>
<p> In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nulla ut lorem sed felis blandit pretium.</p>
<p> Donec eget turpis ac ante gravida aliquet at nec magna.</p>
<p> Curabitur eleifend massa id sapien iaculis scelerisque. </p>
<p>Sed interdum, sapien ac laoreet tempus, orci turpis tristique sapien, </p>
<p>at ultrices dolor nulla eget dui. Vivamus sit amet turpis et erat vehicula tincidunt. Etiam a sodales neque.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In which browser do you see that effect? I can't see anything like it in FF19 and chrome26.

Comment: Not able to reproduce it. What browser/platform?

Comment: No problems here (Chrome 24 or Chrome 26 Canary). Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XR6RJ/

Comment: Fx19/Chrome24 on osx - try removing your "normalised css" from your fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<p>` element has some top margin by default. Add a CSS rule to reset just the first paragraph like this:

```
p:first-of-type {
    margin-top:0;
}
```

Comment: But the first `<p>` in the first column wouldn't have any more margin than the first in the second column.

Comment: however it does the trick. But why does it do the trick? Because the first P in the second column is not really the first P but a continuation of the list from previous column? I even needed an !important

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize it would need the `!important` directive. Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Austin that **p: first-of-type { margin-top:0; }** fixes the issue.

My approach to troubleshooting this issue would have been to remove all p tags temporarily ... in other words filled all columns with just straight "Lorem ipsum" text without any p tags. When you do that top of all columns line up immediately ... so that way then you know for certain it was a p tag formatting issue.